# Bizzare multibyte preg_replace issue. It is changing my data to smily faces!

Tags: php, preg-replace

Using PHP 5.3.1 on windows.

I am just trying to add spaces between numbers and letters, but PHP is mangling my data!

```
$text = "TUES:8:30AM-5:00PMTHURS:8:30AM-5:00PMSAT:8:00AM-1:00PM";
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)/","\1 \2",$text);
> TUES:8:☺ ☻AM-5:☺ ☻PMTHURS:8:☺ ☻AM-5:☺ ☻PMSAT:8:☺ ☻AM-1:☺ ☻PM
```

My file type ANSI, no there is no unicode in the source.

What the fun is going on here?

Comment: out of interest, what happens if you use '$' as your backreference indicator, instead of '\'? ie:  ..."$1 $2",$text); I'm betting '\1' is getting translated to something funky... notice the strange characters don't change between the minutes input being '30' and '00'

Comment: You have to adjust your expression in any case. `\w` contains digits too.

Comment: @Felix, I was using ([0-9]+)([A-Z]+) before but i was trying anything to get rid of those funky chars. Changed back for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `$` are your backreference indicator, not '\':

```
echo preg_replace("/(\d)(\w)/","$1 $2",$text);
```

I'm betting `\1` is getting translated to something funky... notice the strange characters don't change between the minutes input being '30' and '00'

the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) says you should double-escape your backreference, or use `$` (if you are using a version 4.04 or newer)

Comment: This seems to fix it: http://codepad.org/Oi4nrPe0 but the expression has to be adjusted.

Comment: yeh i did notice that - I think you need /(\d+)(\w)/ to get contiguous digits

Answer (score 2):

You should use double backslash when you using them in string separated by double quotes:

```
echo preg_replace("/(\d)(\w)/","\\1 \\2",$text);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\1` and `\2` are being escaped by PHP, and being interpreted as ASCII codes 1 and 2, which in most standard Windows fonts show up as the two smiley faces you're seeing (when I run the same program on my Linux box, I get character code symbols 0001 and 0002 instead of the smiley faces).

If you want to actually use the regex replacement symbols, you need to do one of two things:

1. Use single quotes for your regex strings, so that the slashes aren't used as escaping characters by PHP:

   ```
   preg_replace('/(\d)(\w)/','\1 \2',$text);
   ```
2. Use double-quotes, but escape the slashes:

   ```
   preg_replace("/(\\d)(\\w)/","\\1 \\2",$text);
   ```

I'd suggest the single quote solution as it's easier to read.

Be aware that with double quotes, PHP escaping will always take precedence over regex escaping. This can affect both your regex pattern and the replacement strings. Many PHP escaped characters are the same for regex anyway - for example, `\n` will work the same in the regex pattern regardless of whether it is escaped by PHP or by regex. But there are some which do not work the same - as you've discovered - so you need to be careful.